# O_RDWR permission denied

Tags: c, unix, permissions

I created this file

```
char *output = "big";
creat(output, O_RDWR);
```

When I'm trying to read the file

```
 cat big
```

I'm getting permission denied. Whats wrong with my code? How to create a file with read and write permission mode?

with ls -l, the permission of big looked like this

```
----------
```

what does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misinterpeted the mode argument. From the man page:

```
          mode specifies the permissions to use in case a new file is cre‐
          ated.  This argument must be supplied when O_CREAT is  specified
          in  flags;  if  O_CREAT  is not specified, then mode is ignored.
          The effective permissions are modified by the process's umask in
          the   usual  way:  The  permissions  of  the  created  file  are
          (mode & ~umask).  Note that this mode  only  applies  to  future
          accesses of the newly created file; the open() call that creates
          a read-only file may well return a read/write file descriptor.
```

and also

```
   creat()    is    equivalent    to    open()   with   flags   equal   to
   O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC.
```

So, a more appropriate call might look like:

```
int fd = creat(output, 0644); /*-rw-r--r-- */
```

If you want to open it `O_RDWR` though, then just use `open()`:

```
int fd = open(output, O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC, 0644);
```

Comment: `0666` would be more appropriate, since the umask applies.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a permission issue, start trying to see if creat doesn't returns -1, if so, print the errno value, with perror(""), so that you could resolve the problem.

Imho, i'd rather use open() to do this, because as mentionned in the creat man page, 
"Note that open() can open device special files, but creat() cannot create them; ..", and
"creat() is equivalent to open() with flags equals to O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC", and this doesn't talks about the permissions..

it would be the exact same result if you did this:

```
char*   output = "big";
int     fd;

fd = open(output, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
// do whaterver you want to do in your file
close(fd);
```

For more information, "man 2 open"

Comment: Hmm no, that doesn't make sense.. did you create it with creat() or with open() ? the "S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR" part of the open() functions is useful at the creation time of the file, it defines its permission. As written in the man page, "S_IRUSR -> user has read permission", "S_IWUSR -> user has write permission", the "|" is logic gate that makes the result between S_IRUSR and S_IWUSR to be 0600, as 00000100 | 00000010 = 00000110 = 6. the 6 in 0600 :)